# How to make script work on in app browsers

Tags: javascript, html

I have code that plays audio on page load, and shows visuals in the form of an equalizer on the page. This works well in chrome and other browser (both on pc and mobile). However, when the link is opened on FB messenger an in app browser opens and the script no longer works. Please refer to images.

Working (chrome): 
[image]

Not Working (FB messenger In app Browser): 
[image]

As you can see the in app browser completely cuts out the equalizer and the music is no longer playing. How do I fix this issue?

```js
window.onload = function() {
  function renderVisual() {
    var analyser = context.createAnalyser();

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    src.connect(analyser);
    analyser.connect(context.destination);

    analyser.fftSize = 256;

    var bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
    console.log(bufferLength);

    var dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);

    var WIDTH = canvas.width;
    var HEIGHT = canvas.height;

    var barWidth = (WIDTH / bufferLength) * 3;
    var barHeight;
    var x = 0;

    function renderFrame() {
      requestAnimationFrame(renderFrame);

      x = 0;

      analyser.getByteFrequencyData(dataArray);

      ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

      for (var i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++) {
        barHeight = dataArray[i];

        var r = barHeight + (25 * (i / bufferLength));
        var g = 250 * (i / bufferLength);
        var b = 50;

        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + 0 + "," + 0 + "," + 0 + ")";
        ctx.fillRect(x, HEIGHT - barHeight, barWidth, barHeight);

        x += barWidth + 8;
      }
    }

    renderFrame();
  }

  var context = new AudioContext();
  var file = document.getElementById("thefile");
  var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
  audio.src = "song.mp3";
  audio.load();
  var src = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
  audio.play();
  renderVisual();

  file.onchange = function() {
    var files = this.files;
    audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);
    audio.load();
    audio.play();
    renderVisual();
  };
};
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <audio style="display:none" id="audio" controls></audio>
  <iframe style="display:none" src="silence.mp3" allow="autoplay" id="audio" style="display:none"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: What type of mobile device(s) are you testing it on?

Comment: I am using an Android